# equivalent of Or in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
 if (bl != closeButtonLabel)
 {
     if (bl != minimiseButtonLabel)
     {
         optionPanel.Controls.Remove(bl);
     }
 }
```

Is there a way to do this in 1 if but check the 2 conditions?

At VB it's easy, you place 'Or' and not 'OrElse' but in c# there is only '||'.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `||` *is* the Or equivalent, but I suspect you really want And which is `&&`

Comment: ...if only there was some sort of [authoritative online reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)....

Comment: `OrElse` and `||` are exactly the same operator, just in different languages.  If you want to use an `OrElse`, you have `||`, which does exactly that.

Comment: Robert is right, you want an *AND*. `if bl does not equal x or b1 does not equal y` is the same as `if bl equals x and bl equals y`, which will never be true (assuming `x` and `y` are not equal themselves).

Comment: @Servy - Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but it looks to me like the OP is asking for is `Or`, not `OrElse`, which would be `|` (even though `&&` is what they *should* be using)

Comment: Title and sample code don't seem to agree... code shows "and" as nested `if`, but title/text talks about `or`...

Comment: @CodeMaverick His code has no side effects, and so there is no reason to not short circuit, but yes, I guess I can see that.

Comment: @RobertH || is the OrElse equivilent. Likewise && is the AndAlso equivilent. | is the Or operator while & is the And operator. They are not to be confused as being the same thing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks to DeMorgin's Law you can treat the two interchangeably.

Comment: @KoBE Thanks for the clarification - I haven't looked at VB since the 4.0 days :-D

Comment: @RobertH Not a problem. I once had them confused until someone explained them to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the logical AND operator, '&&'.

```
if (bl != closeButtonLabel && bl != minimiseButtonLabel)
    optionPanel.Controls.Remove(bl);
```

You don't need the logical Or operator here, `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say out loud, what you want: bl should be differnt fom closeButtonLabel **AND** it shoud be different from minimisButtonlabel

```
if (bl != closeButtonLabel && bl != minimiseButtonLabel) {...}
```

or if you really want to use **OR**

```
if (!(bl == closeButtonLabel || bl == mimimizeButtonLabel)) {...}
```

([DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws))

Answer (score 0):

```
if(bl != closeButtonLabel && bl != minimiseButtonLabel)
   {
      //do work
   }
```